# Cmake is not finding "CodeCoverage"

Tags: cmake

I am seeing this error when trying to compile/run some gtest. I don't know where this module should be coming from, as a search on google or here on stackoverflow hasn't provided anything relevant.This include is needed for the "append_coverage_compiler_flags" command.

Here are some of the installed tools/libraries versions installed, obtained by --version:
cmake 3.26.4
python 3.8.10
gcovr 6.0 (expected this to provide CodeCoverage).

Tried on WSL UBuntu 18.04 and 20.04. This only happens on one machine, a second machine that also has WSL Ubuntu 20.04 has no problem with this.

Any help would be appreciated. I can also provide any additional information.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Whatever project you try to build wants to include a file `CodeCoverage.cmake`. Would be helpful to know the project you're working on.

Comment: Hi @Friedrich, thank you for you reply. Yes, this file was missing from the project directory.